# Android - Shadow size not affected when changing elevation

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an Android application targeting android Lollipop and above and I looked into the elevation  property to achieve a shadow under the elements (namely buttons, cards and bottom navigation view).

The issue I'm facing is that when changing the `android:elevation` value within the XML, the shadow size is not affected. What I've tried and read:

- I've read that the elevation does not work unless the view has a background, which mine does have (posted below).
- Other problems around SO states that they do not have a shadow at all, in my case I do have a shadow under the views but its size is unaffected by the elevation property.

Concerning the code, you can find below my button style and the fragment's layout.

**Button Style**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <style name="Search" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|start</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/lightText</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/main_search_textSize</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/main_search</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
        <item name="android:text">@string/search</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">@dimen/main_search_elevation</item>
        <item name="android:drawableStart">@drawable/ic_main_search</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/main_search_padding</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/main_search_padding</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">@dimen/main_search_padding</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Fragment Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@color/lightBackground"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        style="@style/Search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/main_search_height"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">24dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">24dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="main_nav_icon_padding">6dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="main_search_height">54dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="main_search_marginTop">72dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="main_search_elevation">24dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="main_search_padding">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="main_search_textSize">20sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And here's what I'm getting (no matter what the elevation property is):

[image: Search button screenshot]

Note that the shadow does change when long pressing the button, and it is not being clipped in any way.

Therefore, any idea what seems to be the issue?

Comment: can you check your manifest if your HardwareAcceleration is true or false?

Comment: Try `cardview` instead

Comment: @FurqanKhan neither, it is not set. When setting it to `true` I got the same result as above. When setting it to `false`, the shadows disappeared all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey your question seemed really useful so I decided to have a go at it. I hope this helps you, if someone has a better way do post it.

Firstly I think the main issue is that the Button Style you are using has some [StateListAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/StateListAnimator.html) that is controlling the elevation for your button, so no matter what value you set as elevation it gets overridden. The easiest solution is to simply add

```
<item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
```

to your custom "Search" style and now the button will show the elevation you are setting using `<item name="android:elevation">@dimen/main_search_elevation</item>` in the same style.

But this will be like a static view which will give you an elevated look but no cool animated changes when you click or long press  etc.

In order to have those animations you will need to create your custom StateListAnimator using [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator). I created one as an example. Create android resource directory `animator` and add an xml file where you will write the custom animation required.

Here's the **custom_animator.xml** i created

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--For when your button is pressed-->
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="300"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="12dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="300"
                android:propertyName="elevation"
                android:valueTo="12dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>

    <!--For when your button is in its normal state-->
    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="300"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="4dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="300"
                android:propertyName="elevation"
                android:valueTo="4dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>

</selector>
```

You will need to set custom dimensions as per your requirement for when the button is in its base state and when it is pressed. I made use of `4dp` and `12dp` respectively as it seemed more than enough

That's it, now you simply need to add this as a stateListAnimator to your style

```
    <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@animator/custom_animator</item>
```

and it should be working. Note that in this case again `android:elevation` won't work only the values defined in your animator will reflect. So you may remove `<item name="android:elevation">@dimen/main_search_elevation</item>` as its isn't needed.

Referenced a few blogs on medium and other posts on SO, to know how all this worked.
Try this and let us know if it worked for you.

Comment: You were right., the `stateListAnimator` was the culprit. But I tried the `custom_animator`, the elevation is not changing on press. In addition, any idea if the elevation shadow can be moved (x,y) and have its color changed?

Comment: Did you make sure the elevation values were different for its idle state and when it was pressed otherwise there's no visible difference. If it still doesn't work you can try changing from ```"elevation"``` to ```"translationZ"``` in the propertyName. If it still doesn't you can try combining both by wrapping the ```<objectAnimator></objectAnimator>``` in a ```<set></set>```.

Comment: For custom shadows etc you may refer [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping#Shadows) as I don't have much experience with it.

Comment: edited my answer to use both, your case sounds like what happens when its set to null. Strange, I am using the xmls you've posted above and it runs fine for me

Comment: On keeping the button pressed the shadow does increase to the new value specified. not sure what is causing this issue in your case.